# Adding class angular 2

Tags: arrays, angular

I am adding some animation on element, only problem beside style i need to add class also, this is what i have for now in my component.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-shipment-list',
    templateUrl: './shipment-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./shipment-list.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        trigger('slideInOut', [
            state('in', style({
                transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
            })),
            state('out', style({
                transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)'
            })),
            transition('in => out', animate('400ms ease-in-out')),
            transition('out => in', animate('400ms ease-in-out'))
        ]
})
```

Only problem is that beside this attribute style i need to add class opened when is **in** and remove class opened when is **out**?

```
 filtersState: string = 'out';
    toggleFilters() {
        // 1-line if statement that toggles the value:
        this.filtersState = this.filtersState === 'out' ? 'in' : 'out';
    }
```

HTML

```
<app-shipment-list-filters [@slideInOut]="filtersState"></app-shipment-list-filters>
<button type="button" (click)="toggleFilters()" class="btn btn-info">No filter active</button>
```

Comment: why don't use the old dirty jquery :) ? ... addClass on the item?

Comment: In angular 2 i dont use jquery

Comment: why? .... you can .. and also in my experience sometimes it help you very much .. for exmaple for charts and more that are not portered on Angular ... bu you can also use elementRef ..get the elemnt html and add the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngclass):

> A [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) is a good way to add or remove a single class.

So, just try:

```
<app-shipment-list-filters [@slideInOut]="filtersState"
                           [class.opened]="filtersState === 'in'">
</app-shipment-list-filters>
<button type="button" 
        (click)="toggleFilters()" 
        class="btn btn-info">No filter active</button>
```